# Ошибка в FindWindowA и FindWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

Как сделать подключение string к `FindWindowA string WindowNames; string ClassNames;`?

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "");
```

Comment: А вы точно правильно указали заголовок окна? Попробуйте FindWindowW, чтобы исключить проблему локали. Также моежте попробовать Spy++ чтобы найти это окно и посмотреть какой у него точно заголовок.

Comment: Сможете скинуть пример как FindWindowW оформляется ?

Comment: HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"MyRope - Блокнот"); только ваш исходник должен быть сохранён в utf8 думаю.

Comment: Всё равно ошибка.

Comment: Как то ещё это исправить можно?

Comment: Может у вас в заголовке ошибка? `L"MyRope — Блокнот"` (другое тире)

Comment: В процессах написано Блокнот , раскрываю блокнот и там уже написано MyRope.txt - Блокнот

Comment: Как можно другим способом подключатся к процессам?

Comment: @АлександрПан, в моём Блокноте совсем другое тире, не то что у вас "log — Блокнот"

Answer (score 2):

Стояла не та тире , стояла обычная , нужно было ставить тире — , чтобы её поставить зажимайте alt + на нумпаде 0151